# Passing one variable out of 3 variables based on switch command calculations to app with getter,muation,action in store.js

Tags: vue.js, vuex

i want to  Passing one variable out of 3 variables based on switch command calculations to app with getter,mutation,action in store.js

this is my store.js code :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from  'vuex'
Vue.use(Vuex)

let adminRoute= [
    { icon: 'mdi-account-group-outline', text: '  مدیریت کاربران ' ,link:'users'},
    { icon: 'mdi-account-badge-outline', text: 'آخرین مطالبات ثبت شده ' ,link:'demands'},
    { icon: 'mdi-checkbox-marked-circle-outline', text: 'تایید حساب کاربری' ,link:'verify'},
];
let SuperAdminRoute= [
    { icon: 'mdi-account-group-outline', text: '  مدیریت کاربران ' ,link:'users'},
    { icon: 'mdi-account-badge-outline', text: 'آخرین مطالبات ثبت شده ' ,link:'demands'},
    { icon: 'mdi-checkbox-marked-circle-outline', text: 'تایید حساب کاربری' ,link:'verify'},
];
let NormalRoute= [
    { icon: 'mdi-account-group-outline', text: '  مدیریت مطالبات خود ' ,link:'selfDemand'},
    { icon: 'mdi-account-badge-outline', text: '  ارسال گزارش تخلف  ' ,link:'addReport'},
    { icon: 'mdi-checkbox-marked-circle-outline', text: 'تایید حساب کاربری' ,link:'verify'},
];
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state:{
      'pic':'',
       'items':''
    },
    mutations:{
     setProfile:(state ,Pic)=>{
       state.pic=Pic;
     },
        setItem:(state,Item)=>{
         state.items=Item
        }
    },
    actions:{
        setItem(context){
            let level=localStorage.getItem('loggedLevel');
            switch (level) {
                case "21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3":
                    context.commit('setItem',adminRoute);
                    break;
                case "83eebac535d14f791f6ee4dbefe689dc":
                    context.commit('setItem',SuperAdminRoute);
                    break;
                default:
                    context.commit('setItem',NormalRoute);

            }

        }
    },
    getters:{
        getItems:state =>{
            return state.items;
        }
    }
})
```

i using this code to get items but items in empty in my component
admin Route, SuperAdmin Root and normal route
These are my arrays

Comment: Are you [dispatching](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions) your action once? If so, how?

Comment: Furthermore, is there a particular reason you want to store the array in a state and not use a getter that returns the array based on user access level?